# Cursor index out of bounds Exception, Android database

Tags: android, database, gyroscope

I am doing an android app. I am trying to get the rows of the database a view them in a text view. At the begining I want to take the first row of the database. Then I use the gyroscope in order to slide the quotes in the screen. But I get this error. Can anyone help me please? Thanks a lot.

This is SlideShow class

```
package com.example.prova1;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class SlideQuote extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
 //a TextView
 private TextView quote;
 private TextView author;
 //the Sensor Manager
 private SensorManager sManager;
 float x;
 int id;
 int total;
 String s1,s2;
  Database quotedatabase = new Database(this);


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_quote);

        //get the TextView from the layout file
        quote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
id=1;
        //get a hook to the sensor service

        sManager= (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
     if(sManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE).size()!=0){
      Sensor s =sManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE).get(o);
      sManager.registerListener(this,s ,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      quotedatabase.getQuote(id, s1, s2);
      quote.setText(s1);
      author.setText(s2);
    }
    }
    //when this Activity starts
    @Override
 protected void onResume()
 {
  super.onResume();
  /*register the sensor listener to listen to the gyroscope sensor, use the
  callbacks defined in this class, and gather the sensor information as quick
  as possible*/
  sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
 }

  //When this Activity isn't visible anymore
 @Override
 protected void onStop()
 {
  //unregister the sensor listener
  sManager.unregisterListener(this);
  super.onStop();
 }

 @Override
 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1)
 {
  //Do nothing.
 }

 @Override
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
 {
  //if sensor is unreliable, return void
  if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
  {
   return;
  }
  //else it will output the Roll, Pitch and Yawn values
  x=event.values[2];
  total=quotedatabase.getQuotesCount();

  if(x>25){
   if(id==total)
   {id=1;
   }
   else{

   id++;
   }
      quotedatabase.getQuote(id, s1, s2);
      quote.setText(s1);
      author.setText(s2);

  }
  if(x<-25){
   if(id==1)
   {id=total;}
   else{
   id--;}

      quotedatabase.getQuote(id, s1, s2);
      quote.setText(s1);
      author.setText(s2);
  }
  }
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  sManager.unregisterListener(this);
  Intent backIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), Quote.class);
       finish();
       startActivity(backIntent);

 }


 }
```

And this is the database:

```
package com.example.prova1;

/**This class is for the database that is used to store quotes*/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 public Database(Context quoteContext){

 super(quoteContext, "quoteDB", null, 1);

 }

 @Override
 //Create database
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

  String query = "CREATE TABLE quotelist ( quoteId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, textQuote TEXT ,textAuthor TEXT)";
  String query1 = "INSERT INTO quotelist  VALUES ( '1', 'RAI', 'uku')";


    database.execSQL(query);
    database.execSQL(query1);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS quotelist";

   database.execSQL(query);
   onCreate(database);
  }

 //Insert quotes into database 
public void insertItem(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){

  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  values.put("textQuote", queryValues.get("textQuote"));
  values.put("textAuthor", queryValues.get("textAuthor"));

  database.insert("quotelist", null, values);

  database.close();

 }

//Update the quotes into the database

public int updateItem(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {

 SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

 values.put("textQuote", queryValues.get("textQuote"));
 values.put("textAuthor", queryValues.get("textAuthor"));

 return database.update("quotelist", values, "quoteId" + " = ?", new String[] {queryValues.get("quoteId") });

}

//Delete quotes into the database

public void deleteItem(String id){

 SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

 String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM quotelist WHERE quoteId='" + id + "'";

 database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
 database.close();


}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllItems(){

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM quotelist";

 SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

 Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

 if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

  do{

   HashMap<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

   itemMap.put("quoteId", cursor.getString(o));
   itemMap.put("textQuote", cursor.getString(1));
   itemMap.put("textAuthor", cursor.getString(2));


  itemArrayList.add(itemMap);

  } while(cursor.moveToNext());

 }
 database.close();

 return itemArrayList;

}

public HashMap<String, String> getItemInfo(String id){

 HashMap<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

 SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM quotelist WHERE quoteId='" + id + "'";

 Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

 if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

  do{

   itemMap.put("quoteId", cursor.getString(o));
   itemMap.put("textQuote", cursor.getString(1));
   itemMap.put("textAuthor", cursor.getString(2));

  } while(cursor.moveToNext());

 }

 return itemMap;

}

public void getQuote(int id, String s1,String s2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("quotelist", new String[] { "quoteId",
            "textQuote", "textAuthor" }, "quoteId" + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
s1=cursor.getString(1);
s2=cursor.getString(2);


}
public int getQuotesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM  quotelist" ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

The error is  atthis line :   s1=cursor.getString(1);  at DatabaseClass

and at line: quotedatabase.getQuote(id, s1, s2); at ShowQuote class

Answer (score 1):

This error means there is no data in your cursor. Does your database have data in it? Also you should check the result of moveToFirst as a false value will show you if the cursor is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here: s1=cursor.getString(1); and 
s2=cursor.getString(2);
If the string length is 0, you can not get the second character and you will get an outofboundexception.

Also it has no effect to execute this code. In this case you give a string to your methode. This S1 in your method is not the same string as you gave to your method. By giving a variable to a method JAVA creates a copy of this variable.

Comment: If this was true he would get a CursorOutofBound: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2 or something like that, but I agree with the part about it having no effect on the code, though it should be made clear that it creates a copy of a basic type that is not an Object (Strings behave as basic types)